# Specifying a foreign key in a join table rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activerecord, self-join

I am joining my `Product` model to itself `:through` the model `BundleConstituent`.  With this configuration, a product (bundle) can have many products (constituents) and those constituents can have many bundles.

**Product model**

```
has_many :bundle_constituents, dependent: :destroy
has_many :constituents, through: :bundle_constituents
has_many :products, through: :bundle_constituents, foreign_key: 'constituent_id'
```

**BundleConstituent model**

```
create_table :bundle_constituents do |t|
  t.references :product, null: false, foreign_key: true, index: false
  t.integer :constituent_qty
  t.references :constituent, null: false, foreign_key: {to_table: :products}, index: false
  t.index [:product_id, :constituent_id], unique: true

  t.timestamps
end
```

I am able to create a record easily enough in the `BundleConstituent` model and query a bundle with `Product.find(2).constituents` with no issue.  **The problem** happens when I attempt to get the bundles belonging to a constituent with `Product.find(8).products`, the resultant query looks for join records with `product_id = 8` in `BundleConstituent`, rather than `constituent_id=8`.  See below for the complete output from the console:

```
2.6.6 :015 > c.products
  Product Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  `products`.* FROM `products` INNER JOIN `bundle_constituents` ON `products`.`id` = `bundle_constituents`.`product_id` WHERE `bundle_constituents`.`product_id` = 8 LIMIT 11
 => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>
```

I would think that specifying the `:foreign_key` on `has_many :products` in the Product model would take care of this, but it seems not to.  How can I force the query to reference the `constituent_id` column and not the `product_id` column?

**EDIT:** (from my comment below)

I created a workaround using a scope to achieve what I'm after:

```
scope :respective_bundles, -> (const_id){ includes(:bundle_constituents).all.select{|i| i.bundle_constituents.present?}.select{|i| i.bundle_constituents.select{|j| j.constituent_id == const_id}}}
```

where `const_id` is id of the id of the constituent product in question. Still, this seems like a hack and I'd be interested in something more elegant without needing to construct such a cumbersome query.

Comment: You cannot use foreign_key with through because the through relationship already specifies the foreign_key. I am still a bit unclear what you are going for here though.

Comment: @engineersmnky good to know!  I am dong a self join so that bundle products can have many constituent products and constituent products can have many bundle products.  I am able to query the associated constituent products given the bundle product (`some_bundle.constituents`) but I can't query the bundle products, given a constituent product.  The reason for this seems to be that I cannot figure out a way to tell the systtem to use the `constituent_id` in the join table instead of the `product_id` (short of manually writing a scope or something like that)

Comment: @engineersmnky To clarify, the `product_id` in the join table refers to bundle products.  Bundles and constituents are both records of `Product`

Comment: @engineersmnky I created a workaround using a scope: `scope :respective_bundles, -> (const_id){ includes(:bundle_constituents).all.select{|i| i.bundle_constituents.present?}.select{|i| i.bundle_constituents.select{|j| j.constituent_id == const_id}}}`  where `const_id` is id of the id of the constituent product in question.  Still, this seems like a hack and I'd be interested in something more elegent without needing to construct such a cumbersome query.